# Joining tables and displaying multiple columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  timestamp
FROM seller_v2.dashboard_view dashboard
INNER JOIN seller_v2.users users
ON dashboard.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

This returns a list of timestamps. I want to add more columns such as name and email. When I run this query:

```
SELECT
  timestamp,
  name
FROM seller_v2.dashboard_view dashboard
INNER JOIN seller_v2.users users
ON dashboard.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

**I get this error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 3:     timestamp,
                     ^**

How do I add the additional columns?

Comment: extra `,` after `name`

Comment: Removed. Still getting this error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 2:   timestamp,
                   ^

Comment: `timestamp` is a reserved keyword. You can't use it as a column name unless you escape it. I wonder how the first query worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  `timestamp`,
  name
FROM seller_v2.dashboard_view dashboard
INNER JOIN seller_v2.users users
ON dashboard.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

I would also suggest using the alias's.

So dashboard.timestamp, dashboard.name (I am guessing they are the correct aliases).

Comment: Still getting this error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 2:   timestamp,
                   ^

Comment: Ok what table is timestamp and name from?

Are they from dashboard_view or users?

Try

SELECT dashboard.timestamp, dashboard.name FROM